# SQL : How to record the name of a file from a repository in a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a table in SQL Server which I feed using a bulk command on data from a csv file (in a repository).

How can I write a loop command to detect all the name files in a repository and use them in a variable.

I'll call this script with a batch file.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_TMP (Column1 VARCHAR(35),Column2 VARCHAR(35));

BULK INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_TMP]
FROM 'C:\DATA\Products\Source\File1.csv'

WITH
    (  
        FIELDTERMINATOR =';',
        ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
    );
```

Comment: Why not let the batch file do the looping? If I were to solve this, I would use an SSIS package with a "foreach loop container".

Comment: No ETL is used in my compagny. ( not even Talend ) . Any idea on how i can do this using a batch script  ?

Comment: Ask your server administrator for that. The idea is to create a FOR loop to loop through the csv files in the folder. Each filename found can be passed to a subroutine that handles the filename, for example import the data from the file using the BCP command line tool.